# Is there a way to show number and percent in stacked bar graphs in Quickbase?

Tags: quickbase

I'd essentially want to create what's in the link in QuickBase, but from what I've seen, it isn't a straightforward procedure.

https://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/image_thumb11.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can use display both value using the native/built-in charts. You could build a Code Page in Quickbase that queries data using the API and then renders a chart using a library such a Highcharts or Charts.js

Comment: Thank you, Erich. This is very helpful. Do you know of any resources that could help me learn how to do this? I had a hard time finding anything helpful for a beginner from my online research, unfortunately.

Comment: Ya absolutely. So Quickbase code page support front end development languages. You will use HTML and CSS for the interface and Javascript for logic. There is Code Page Workshop app available in the Quickbase exchange: https://login.quickbase.com/db/main?a=AppDetail&ID=3874&app_name=Code%20Page%20Workshop